# How to publish platform event from LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, aura, platform-event

I need to start flow from lwc,
I am trying to publish a platform event from LWC to start platform event flow.
Don't want to use aura flow.

can we use something like `import {events} from '@salesforce/events/Event_Name__e'` for publish from API
[doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_api.htm)

create platform event body:
{
"Printer_Model__c" : "XZO-5"
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options: - Either [empApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_lc.htm) or Using [Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_apex.htm). The way you want is not supported in Lightning Web Component.

- The empApi component provides access to methods for subscribing to a streaming channel and listening to event messages.
- The empApi component uses a shared CometD-based Streaming API
  connection, enabling you to run multiple streaming apps in the
  browser for one user. The connection is not shared across user
  sessions.
- In Apex, either you can use EventBus.publish to publish platform events or you can consume the [API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_api.htm)

Also, Check [Emp API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation) Lightning Web Component

Comment: Thanks @sanket for your reply, In emp api there is no publish bus property exposed to UI component. how could we do it?

Comment: You'll need to use apex to publish the event. EmpAPI helps us to subscribe only.