# createRecord (UI RecordAPI) in LWC Doesn't Fire Platform Event

Tags: lightning-web-components, platform-event, create-records, ui-api

Is it possible to fire a PE from within LWC without needing an Apex controller by using `createRecord` UI API?

Here is what I have as a ***headless*** quick-action component

```
import { createRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import HeadlessQuickAction from "c/headlessQuickAction";
import PE_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/MY_Platform_Event__e";

export default class MyHeadlessAction extends HeadlessQuickAction {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.setHeadlessActionFunction(this.share);
    }

    share() {
        const fields = {};
        fields.Field1__c = "field one value";
        fields.Field2__c = JSON.stringify({
            aa: "test",
            bb: "test",
            cc: "test"
        });

        const recordInput = { apiName: PE_OBJECT.objectApiName , fields };

        createRecord(recordInput)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("Event published successfully", response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error publishing event:", error);
            });
    }
}
```

There are 2 problems with this;

1. `PE_OBJECT.objectApiName` always gives `MY_Platform_Event__c` and NOT `MY_Platform_Event__e`
2. When I hardcode the value correctly, that is `MY_Platform_Event__e`, this time the execution seems to go through the server and gives the following error

````
    body: 
          errorCode: "ENTITY_NOT_QUERYABLE"
          message: "Unable to view record since MY_Platform_Event__e is not queryable."
          statusCode: 403```
````

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/332837/how-to-publish-platform-event-from-lwc This might help

Comment: This approach can't work, because Platform Events are published, not inserted/created.